# gmaps4rails selecting marker by id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I want to make an info window open when a user hover's over a given link.

I've given all the markers ids and the links have the same id.  I can make the hover open an info window, I'm just not sure how to get it to open it according the link's id and the correct marker.

Js: it pops open an info box on the map, just unsure of how to specify the correct id on the map.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
        $(".items li a").on("mouseover", function() {
          //alert(this.id);
          var marker = Gmaps.map.markers[0]; //this.id
          var map         = Gmaps.map.serviceObject
          marker.infowindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Markers:

```
@json = @events.to_gmaps4rails do |event, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/events/hover", :locals => { :event => event })
  marker.title   "#{event.place.name}"
  marker.json({ :id => event.id })
end
```

Links:

```
<%= link_to event.place.name, pub_path(event.place), id: event.id %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  You have to iterate thru all the markers in order find the correct one. Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you could do something like:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  $(".items li a").on("mouseover", function() {

    //id of selected marker
    i = $(this).attr("id");
    marker = _.find(Gmaps.map.markers, function(obj) { return obj.id == i })
    var map         = Gmaps.map.serviceObject          
    marker.infowindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);
  });
}
```